# Error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file (project file name).metaproj

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, cmake, tfsbuild

We have just upgraded a build server to TFS 2013, and Visual Studio 2013, and are running into problems. We have a MSBuild (.proj) file that triggers the generation of a solution (.sln) file using CMake, and then a sub-MSBuild step that builds this solution. The CMake part finishes without issues, but when MSBuild tries to build it, we get the following error from all the projects in the solution:

Error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file (project file name).metaproj

The metaproj files are not present next to the projects, but as I understand it, these files are never stored to disk but kept in memory instead. The exact same sources still build fine on our 2012 build server, as well as locally using Visual Studio 2013. The only changes we have done are to generate 2013 solutions, and set the ToolVersion to 12.0 for the "bootstrap" MSbuild file.

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable 'MSBuildEmitSolution=1' to see what metaproj files are being constructed, and where? (Optionally, set it on the MSBuild command line using the /p:MSBuildEmitSolution=1 format). This might help you deduce what the problem might be.

Comment: As far as I can see, setting the option on the command line does nothing, you have to use it as an environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the old DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml build process template for building the project on the build server. I gave up on trying to make it work with that template, and converted to the new TfVcTemplate.12.xaml instead, and that solved the issue. 
I still don't know what caused the original issue, but determined  that it was not caused by CMake, as it could be replicated without CMake in the equation.